# Unable to ctrl-click in eclipse while browsing Android runtime classes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, editor

Whenever I try to go to a declaration (Ctrl-Click or F3) while browsing an Android runtime class (e.g. `android.view.View`) nothing happens. If I use F3, the status bar reads "Current text selection cannot be opened in an editor"

This works perfectly when browsing my own classes. It even works for other .jar files that have source attachments.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the Eclipse source itself I found the reason: The `android.jar` file **does not** include any private fields or members. Only public and protected fields/members are compiled in.

I guess this makes sense from the point of view that this file is only needed to be compiled against -- it isn't the actual runtime which is already in the emulator/device in the form of dalvik code. This is, however, a very lamentable decision, as it makes it really awkward to explore the Android code using Eclipse.

So, in short, it isn't possible. I suppose re-compiling the android.jar to include all fields/members would solve the problem.